# Android webview JavascriptInterface doesn't have methods

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a Javascript interface like this:

```
class JsInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    void onSendRequest(String url, String request, String response) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onRequest(url, request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

And in web view I do

```
addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "JsInterface");
getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

However, when I look in google inspect and type `window.JsInterface` it just outputs empty object. That's why I get error `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onSendRequest'` when try to execute my method. On some devices it works fine, but on others it doesn't. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation

> Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, **you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public).** If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

I'm not 100% sure about Java but usually, methods are private by default.

reference
https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

So for you It'd be

```
class JsInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
   public void onSendRequest(String url, String request, String response) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onRequest(url, request, response);
        }
    }
}
```